# Update query mysql to VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

I tried this query on mysql and it works perfectly.

```
UPDATE tblstocklog 
SET quantity = quantity - 5
WHERE(ProductNo = 25370)
AND quantity >= 5
ORDER BY StockNo ASC LIMIT 1
```

But when I tried it with VB.net it doesn't update nor give a error message.

```
con3.Open()

query3 = "UPDATE tblstocklog set Quantity = Quantity - '" & txt_qty.Text & _
"' WHERE (ProductNo = '" & txt_pno.Text & _ 
"') AND Quantity >= '" & txt_qty.Text & "' ORDER by StockNo ASC LIMIT 1"

Dim cmd3 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, con3)
Dim i3 As Integer = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
con3.Close()
```

Comment: My VB is very rusty, but you could try testing for error rather than ignoring them

Comment: (1) Print `query3` and put that in your question; (2) Perhaps  no rows match the conditions.

Comment: There are rows that matches its conditions..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I was in a hurry doing my program and I missed a clear error.

```
Dim cmd3 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(**query**, con3)
```

query should be query3